# Magento2.3.0 Admin side web setup wizard inside extention manager click after loading issue

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.3.0, web-setup-wizard, loader, web

I am using Magento2.3.0 and we have to go to admin side system->Tools->Web Setup Wizard inside Extension manager click after loader has not stopped.

[image]

my console inside getting response[image]

If anyone idea reply me.

Comment: Can you check the console error?

Comment: I check it there extetnions inside responce blank  showing

Comment: Try by doing cache:clean, cache:flush

Comment: please check it my updated question

Comment: already try to cache clean and flush

Comment: in website more than 256 modules including theme modules